# "I only teach you" vs. "I teach only you" vs. "I teach you only"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, word-order

> - I only teach you.
> - I teach only you.
> - I teach you only.

I think that all the sentences have same meaning, but my teacher says that they are different from each other.

I think that the expressions are different but their meaning are same.

Can you help me understand the meaning of each sentence?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Only* is one of the words (like *even*, *too*, and *also*) that have a stressed **focus** word in the sentence.

The focus word takes a heavy contrastive stress in speech, no matter where *only* occurs.

- *She only talked to Mrs. McGrew about **Bill**.* (not talking **about** anybody else)
- *She only talked to **Mrs. McGrew** about Bill.* (not talking **to** anybody else)
- *She only **talked** to Mrs. McGrew about Bill.* (no activity except talking)

In these sentences, *only* appears before the verb phrase, which contains the focus in each case.
It can also appear right before the focus word (or right after, if the focus is a noun).

- *She talked to Mrs. McGrew only about **Bill**.*
- *She talked only to **Mrs. McGrew** about Bill.*
- *She talked to Mrs. McGrew about **Bill** only.*
- *She talked about Bill to **Mrs. McGrew** only.* (this works better at the end of a sentence)

Of course, in writing, there is no stress, so it's harder to tell what the focus is.
So in writing it's safest to put *only* right before the focus word (the word with contrastive stress)

[This rule is discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299), with references and examples.

Comment: I am not the original asker, but I appreciate the wonderful answer. But, I would like to ask if *She talked to Mrs. McGrew about **only** Bill* is also correct.

Comment: It's also grammatical, though it's not colloquial.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Then how about in written English?

Comment: As I said, it's not colloquial, so it marks the sentence as odd, and possibly the writer as a non-native speaker. It's an unnecessary distraction that serves no obvious communicational purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. :) Now I understand that.

Answer (score 3):

The sentences do have different meanings. See the following EXAMPLES. (These are only examples of how the sentences can be interpreted but it depends completely on context, for instance, when, where, who is speaking, and to whom they are spoken.)

```
I only teach you. (meaning merely)
```

Can be taken to mean: ***I am merely your teacher. You must strive to understand what I teach.*** Or ***You must take what I teach and use it.*** Or ***I cannot take credit because I am merely* (only) *the teacher.***

```
I teach only you.
```

This usually means ***I have no other students***. Or ***You are the only student who understands.*** But this second possibility is not normal for this sentence. I mention it because when said that way, the teacher would continue on with more information.

```
I teach you only.
```

This sentence seems incomplete or is phrased by a non-native English speaker. I would normally expect to see this sentence continued with something like: ***I teach you only what I know***, or ***I teach you only what you can understand.*** These express a limit to the scope of the teaching, instead of limiting how many are taught. Also: ***I teach you only until you go home.*** Or ***I teach you only enough to help you pass the test.*** As you can see, each of these limit the material taught.

If the last sentence were spoken by a non-native English speaker, it could mean any one of the above possibilities, because non-native speakers tend to change the location of words within a sentence to match how they speak their first language. In that case the student should seek clarification from the speaker. I would be inclined to think the speaker means to use it in the first context since it was not followed by limits, and there was no mention of other students.

So, to recap with EXAMPLES:

1. `I only teach you.` means *I am merely the teacher.*
2. `I teach only you.` means *I have no other students.*
3. `I teach you only.` means *There are limits to what I teach you.*

I hope this helps clear up some confusion.

Comment: I can't think of a better answer and explanation. Huge huge kudos!!!  I admire people like you!

Answer (score -2):

> - I only teach you.
> - I teach only you.
> - I teach you only.

These sentences all say essentially the same thing, you are only teaching one person.  However, the way the sentences are arranged may change the emphasis slightly.

> I *only* teach you.

*Only* modifies the subject *I*; one can say that the sentence means, *I alone teach you.*

> I teach *only* you.

*Only modifies *teach*; one can be said I teach no-one but you. (nothing rlse is done.

> I teach you *only.* Only modifies *you*. One can say, I teach you only you, no one else, but I do other things.

This is the most I can differentiate these, I hope a linguist comes along and sees more!

Comment: In *I teach only you*, *only* modifies *you*. Adverbs don't go between a verb and a direct object, so *only* has to be an adjective modifying *you*.

Comment: Surely *I only teach you* means *I don't do anything else for you*; *I alone teach you* would be *Only I teach you*.

Comment: Don't forget that the pronoun, you, can also be plural in meaning, as in "I only teach you (my students) I'm not your mother!" :)

Comment: @TimLymington It depends on whether you stress *teach* or *you*.  (See [John Lawler's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/i-only-teach-you-vs-i-teach-only-you-vs-i-teach-you-only/16034#16034).)