# The different positions of "only" in the same sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, conjunctions, adverb-placement

Is there any difference in the following sentences?

> 1. This rule **only** applies to students
> 2. This rule applies to students **only**
> 3. This rule applies **only** to students

If you don't mind, please clarify the  differences in meanings of the above given sentences.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/i-only-teach-you-vs-i-teach-only-you-vs-i-teach-you-only Duplicate topic

Answer (score 1):

> "Only" can be a conjunction, an adverb or an adjective.
>
> It is not correct to end your sentence with a conjunction, but nobody
>   would ever do that anyway.

- This rule *only* applies to students

*Only* can modify *"This rule"*, *"applies"* or *"students"* here, depending on the stress.

- This rule applies to students *only*

Here *"only"* modifies *"students"*. But (don't throw stones at me) this might be considered to be poor style of English.

- This rule applies only to students

Here *"only"* also modifies *"students"*. I would suggest this as most correct of the three.

As a conjunction the word "only" is used as [follows](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only):

- I'd invite Frances to the party, *only* (= but I will not because) I
  don't want her husband to come.
- I'd call him myself, *only* (= but I cannot because) I'm at work all
  day.
- I'd be happy to do it for you, *only* (= but) don't expect it to be
  done before next week.
- This fabric is similar to wool, *only* (= except that it is) cheaper.

Comment: Thank you, So much for your detailed explanation.    by the way can i put like this, "Only this rule applies to students"

Comment: *only* is an adverb here. Not a conjunction.

Comment: @user178049 We know!

Comment: In "This rule *only* applies to students" *only* can only be referring to "applies". The basic rule is that *only* modifies the nearest noun/adjective/adverb. Also, if you are going to mention *only* as a conjunction, it may be helpful to have an example of that use for contrast