# Difference between "the only two" and "only the two"

Tags: phrase-usage, word-order

What is the difference (e.g. usage and meaning) between "(There are) the only two (words)" and "(There are) only the two (words)"?

What is the difference in meaning between

> A form with only the two quotations is submitted

and

> A form with the only two quotations is submitted

Comment: "Those are the only two words I understand of that sentence in Swedish" - "There are only the two words _No Admittance_ written on the board."

Comment: "There are the [only (adjective) two words.]" and "There [are only] (adverb) the two words"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The different positions of "only" in the same sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111059/the-different-positions-of-only-in-the-same-sentence) Also [Does the position of “only” give a different meaning to the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/does-the-position-of-only-give-a-different-meaning-to-the-sentence) and [position of 'only' and the respective change in meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27595/position-of-only-and-the-respective-change-in-meaning), among others

Comment: Then, what is the difference in meaning between "A form with only the two quotations is submitted." and "A form with the only two quotations is submitted." ?