# ONLY and IF: The difference in meaning implied by the difference in emphasis. Help, please

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am not a native speaker, so I cannot entirely sense the difference in the meaning of the following two sentences:

> An action can **only** be legitimate **if** sufficient justifying
> reasons can be addressed to all concerned (affected) parties...

and:

> An action can be legitimate **only if** sufficient justifying reasons
> can be addressed to all concerned (affected) parties...

I do understand that, in the second clause, the ***only if*** is employed to signify a strong formal condition, i.e., that an action can be legitimate only if that condition is met.

However, I do not understand the first clause (...*only be legitimate if*...). What is the emphasis of this first clause? I would very much appreciate your help since I am translating an academic text into my mother tongue, and thus need to be very precise when it comes to nuances in meaning.

Comment: There are two possibilities in your cite context. Either sufficient justifying reasons CAN be addressed (case #1), or they CAN'T (case #2). The significance of ***only*** is that "an action can be legitimate" if case #1 applies - but if case #2 applies ***there is no possibility of the action being legitimate***. That's to say, if something ***only*** applies in one specific context, that's an "exclusive" situation - implying it will ***never*** occur in any other contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I only teach you" vs. "I teach only you" vs. "I teach you only"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/i-only-teach-you-vs-i-teach-only-you-vs-i-teach-you-only). Also [Does the position of “only” give a different meaning to the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/) and [position of 'only' and the respective change in meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27595/) and [The different positions of “only” in the same sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111059/), among others.

Comment: Those sentences mean the same thing to me. There might be some nuance difference, like the first one sounds more natural, and the second one sounds more like formal logic.

Comment: Тhank you very much!! Your answers helped me understand the meaning!!