# Understanding a quote

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Happiness is not something you postpone for the future; it is something you design for the present

What does the author mean by saying 'design for the future'?

Comment: Please only ask ***one*** question in a single post. Your second question here (the "Also" stuff) is probably a duplicate of [“I only teach you” vs. “I teach only you” vs. “I teach you only.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/) Your first question concerns an utterance that's primarily about "playing with language" rather than clearly expressing a logically coherent idea. The author *probably* means you should try to be happy ***now*** rather than endure current misery in hopes that you'll be even happier at some point in the future, but the language used is inherently vague.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking *three completely unrelated questions* (1: the meaning of a quirky stylised "aphorism", 2: the position of "only", 3: which preposition to use after "email").

Comment: Actually I thought of posting them as separate questions but I could post the other question only after 40 mins, thus posted them at once

Comment: However, I am grateful for your answer and would ensure that from next time, I would take care of posting multiple questions separately.

Comment: I didn't know about that time limit, but it's been over an hour now, so I suggest you edit your current text to remove the second and third items, and ***re-post*** the second question if my link doesn't clear things up for you (if it does, you can immediately repost the ***3rd*** question, otherwise you'll just have to wait a little longer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cited text is primarily ***wordplay***, rather than clear communication of an idea. But my guess is the writer was just trying to find a "clever" way of saying what many others have expressed as...

> [*Live for the present, not the future*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Live%20for%20the%20present,%20not%20the%20future%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00UQQ7dwT9FcdLnpjB1RA1do-J2FA:1582643044143&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7987j_OznAhU4UhUIHaX8APYQpwUIIQ&biw=1502&bih=710&dpr=1.25) (that's a ***lot*** of written instances in Google Books)

...the meaning of which I hope I don't need to explain.

---

Some people may think OP's cited example is "well phrased" (or at least, "clever"), but I don't like it much, because the verb form ***to design*** inherently implies making a ***plan for the future***. So the only way to make sense of ***designing for the present*** as somehow being the "opposite" of ***postponing*** one's (future) happiness is to suppose it means *make plans to achieve happiness **as soon as possible** in the future.*

Strictly speaking I doubt ***design*** is really a suitable verb for what the writer is trying to say. It's true that he *might* be advising us to design / plan our lives *with the intention* of being happy in the very near future (which is *almost* the same as "the present").

But most likely he's advising us to ***find / take*** pleasure / happiness *in our current circumstances*. Sometimes that's just a matter of having an optimistic ***attitude*** (look on the bright side; see your glass as "half full" rather than "half empty"). Other times it's a matter of making particular choices (indulge yourself and spend your money ***now***, rather than saving it and waiting until you're too old and decrepit to enjoy it).

Comment: Thanks for your lucid answer