# "date only someone" vs. "only date someone"

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Two friends are talking about their loving lives.

> A: Do you date **only** women who have something wrong with them?
>
> B: I'm not dating anyone.

Usually, adverbs are between subject and main verb, so "**only** date ..." is more likely right.

Should I use "date **only** ..." or "**only** date ..." or both are fine?

It seems a pattern "verb **only**". I cannot find this rule/pattern in  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/only

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: See [this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/i-only-teach-you-vs-i-teach-only-you-vs-i-teach-you-only)

Answer (score 0):

In this case "only" is used as an adverb, therefore its position depends on the focus of the sentence. 
Usually it is put between the subject and the main verb, so:

> Do you only date  women who have something wrong with them?

seems more correct to me, but according the Cambridge dictionary both of them are ok.

Source:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/only

Comment: Usually, adverbs are between subject and main verb, so "**only** date ..." is more likely right.

Comment: It seems a pattern "verb **only**". I cannot find this rule/pattern in  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/only